# How to automatically create Excel graphs from Access data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros, microsoft-access, vba

I have some data in Access from which I have to create Excel graphs every month (data would also be updated every month). So it's creating the same charts with different data every month.

Is there a way to automate this process? I'm thinking about Excel automatically pulling in the updated data for that month from Access and creating a similar graph to the one created last month (from last month's data) in a new Excel file.

I have the idea that a macro could do this but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to create graphs in Excel since you can create a report in Access and a graph to that or use "Graph Wizard". See the following example

[MS Access: Create a graph](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/reports/graph1.php)

If you insist on Excel, I suppose you can save an Excel file with graphs and ODBC data link (Not importing data) as a template and use that to generate the monthly file.

Comment: I want to automate this process of making graph. I know I can do it in access but I want something (eg: running a sas code or VBA) that would automatically populate it in either access or excel.

Comment: Was the stackoverflow answer by Tony any use? Refer to the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629397.aspx)

Comment: I am not a VBA expert. He was really helpful and I tried the code that he provided but I am getting errors and I could not figure out whats mistake I am making. I am looking for a more simple solution. I know SAS very well and thats why I am trying to figure out if I can link SAS to excel to automatically run the code and generate graphs.

Comment: You have not responded to my comments of 7 December against the Stack Overflow version of this question so I do not know if you are still having problems or if you want something different.